# App designed for iPhone 5, showing partially cut views on iPhone 4S

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, xcode5

I started designing an application that would work on both iPad and iPhone. the iPad part is ok, but i am having trouble with making my app look good on both iPhone 4S and iPhone 5. The view is showing partially cut on iPhone 4S screen.

I have seen several solutions regarding using `Autolayout`, it is not working for me. I am coding on `XCODE 5.`

please help.

Comment: If you correctly add constraints and use autolayout they will work fine on both. Your question is to broad. Add some screenshots or code in order to get help.

Comment: @NikosM. actually i am having problem with using constraints. Not able to understand how to use them. If you can provide a helpful link for the same, i will be grateful.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After seeing your comment that you have issues with constrains and autolayout, and not seeing the codes or screen shots of the project you are working on, I find it difficult to offer a specific answer. But I can provide you with a link to a 2 part tutorial written by Matthias which explains the constrains in autolayout in detail. I hope that helps you out. Here is the link: http://www.raywenderlich.com/50317/beginning-auto-layout-tutorial-in-ios-7-part-1

Comment: +1 for the awesome link. Also, I'd suggest buying iOS7 by tutorials. I learnt so much from it.